# Incrementing and re-rendering in vue.js : bug or feature?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get up to speed on vue.js and did come across a behaviour I cannot explain. I am trying to increment and re-render a simple output as follows:

```
<div id="app">
    <h1> Seconds : {{ number }}</h1>
    {{ update() }}
</div>

</body>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            number: 1
        },
        methods: {
            update() {
                setInterval(() => {
                    this.number++
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

All works fine, except that I would have expected this to simply count up 1 ... 2 ... 3 ... 4 ... 5 ... etc. , but instead it doubles the output, i.e. shows 1 ... 2 ... **4** ... **8** ... **16** ... **32** ... etc.

This remains the same, if I replace

```
this.number++
```

with

```
this.number = this.number + 1
```

What is it that I'm missing here? Is this a bug or a "weird" feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the `update` function for every rendering of the component.

And because the rendering is depends on `number` every time the variable changes the component re-render and call `update` again.

The `setInterval` repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet.
[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

So effectively you are creating multiple timers that will increments `number`.

Also calling a function in the `template` is not a good practice what you can do is call the `update` method in the `created` lifecycle hook that will be called only once.

[Created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    number: 1
  },
  created() {
    this.update();
  },
  methods: {
      update() {
          setInterval(() => {
              this.number++
          }, 1000)
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h1> Seconds : {{ number }}</h1>
</div>
```